# int p is not a constant expression in lpNorm<p>

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I wrote this function

```
    template <typename T>
    double norm(const T & v, const int p) {
        return v.template lpNorm<p>();
    }
```

but it doesn't work and gives the error:

```
 error: 'p' is not a constant expression
             return v.template lpNorm<p>();
                                         ^
```

I seem to think that the compiler expects `p` to be known at compile time whereas my `p` is dynamic.

Possibly related:

[Why is this not a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580714/why-is-this-not-a-constant-expression)

[Non-type template argument is not a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177721/non-type-template-argument-is-not-a-constant-expression)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Templates are resolved at compile time ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can partially do it with a limited range of `p`. For `lpNorm` operation it is usually enough.

You've already known that you need a compile-time constant as the template parameter. However as `p` is usually used in a small range (0,1,2,inf), you could use the following trick to make it work for a small sub-set of commonly used `int` values.

```
template<typename T>
double norm(const T & v, const int p) {
  switch (p) {
  case 0:
    return v.template lpNorm<0>();
    break;
  case 1:
    return v.template lpNorm<1>();
    break;
  case 2:
    return v.template lpNorm<2>();
    break;
  case Eigen::Infinity:
    return v.template lpNorm<Eigen::Infinity>();
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could we generate the equivalent of the switch using some template magic?

Comment: To be a bit more specific, I mean something that will take a generic functor and `std::integer_sequence` of possible values at compile-time, and generate the necessary plumbing to select based on run-time values.

Comment: @lisyarus Precisely. That will be very handy to have around, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cant.

Templates are resolved at compile time. This means for each value of `p` in the line `lpNorm<p>()` you will generate code specific to that template. If `p` can be any value then you need to generate code for every possible value which is not a good idea, the compiler is telling you this.

`p` must be known at compile time which means you need to do something like this:

```
template <int p, typename T>
double norm(const T & v) {
```

Then specialize for any value of `p` that you might expect to receive.

If `p` truely is dynamic, then you need a run-time solution, not a compile time solution, so it is likely that you want this:

```
lpNorm(p);
```

(you will obviously need to redefine how `lpNorm` works)

Comment: It would make more sense to make `p` the first template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Templates are resolved at compile-time. And because of that they can't be run-time variables. And despite the `const` in the argument declaration `p` is still a run-time variable.

The `const` in the argument declaration simply means that the function can not change the argument value. It's still possible to call your function with a normal non-constant variable.